# Download email attachment through VB.NET on Outlook Web App

Tags: vb.net

I understand that similar questions have been asked before on Stack Overflow and all over the internet, but my situation is a bit unique. Let me give some context:

I want to make a macro/program that automatically downloads attachments sent from a set of emails (according to date) in a specific folder on the Outlook Web App. The only issue is that this is for my workplace, and the IT department is refusing to give me the password for the outlook account which makes it difficult to sync up the Web App to the on desktop application (I am a pharmacy student who works at a Chemist Warehouse and I'm just doing this as a local pet-project because lockdown is making me bored, it would not be used for all stores).

I have come up with an idea for the solution, essentially I want to use the urlmon ability of VB.Net to download the attachment as a file from the web. I was thinking if I could put a Web Browser control on the form, make it invisible and when the program loads up it automatically goes to the store email (I can get the url), to the appropriate folder. I then want to be able to read the HTML content perhaps? and then download any and all attachments in all emails received today for example in that folder.

I understand this is a unique and weird situation, so any help is much appreciated. If there are any further questions please feel free to ask and I will answer to the best of my ability.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How do you have access to this account if you don't have the password for it?

Comment: To clarify, you're talking about accessing the Outlook.com or Office 365 E-mail **website** in a web-browser and not the desktop Office Outlook program?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you can't use EWS (the Exchange "ActiveSync" web-service API) to access mailbox content? Generally speaking, if you have to resort to screen-scraping through a web-browser then you're doing something wrong...

Comment: Finally - I do not recommend using VB.NET for doing screen-scraping because working with the DOM in VB is painful. If you need something quick-and-dirty that **will** work, then you should write a Chrome Extension in JavaScript, because that will give you quick, easy access to the DOM directly and also let you automate the downloading of files.

Comment: So the email is our store mail and we receive faxed prescriptions from doctors. We normally manually download the faxed prescriptions onto a local drive. I wanna automate this.

Comment: The best way to do that is by using the Outlook Web REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/use-outlook-rest-api - you won't even need a password for that: your sysadmin will be able to get you a special application-specific credential.

Comment: I'll look into this and see what I can do. Thanks for that Dai. Would u be able to point me towards any code examples perhaps similar to my query? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: There are example requests and responses for working with attachments in the documentation page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations#GetAttachmentCollection

Comment: I kept reading through the documents for the Outlook Web REST API and I just got lost in all the documentation. Something about registering the app and so on. I was just wondering if you would be able to help me with what exactly I have to do Dai?

On the other hand, I could write a chrome extension using JavaScript...any idea how I can do that? XD

Comment: I agree that OIDC is a hard concept to understand and is a major barrier for beginners who want to automate Office 365 - so the remaining best option for you is to create a VBA macro in desktop Outlook (actually, this probably the easiest option anyway!). Are you able to access that mailbox using desktop Outlook at all? If so, then enable the "Developer" tab in the Outlook ribbon and open the VBA editor and get crackin'.

Comment: You are about to cry. That was what I had originally created, and it worked at home. I got so excited, went to work and then boom...they don't have the desktop version of Outlook. I asked my boss if he could ask IT for the password so I can download a Outlook onto desktop, and IT was so adamant about not giving it to us. Hence why I wanted to see if there were other ways...like screen scraping maybe? Shall we move this to the chat?

Comment: Sure - I need some entertainment

Comment: Lol, apparently I need more reputation to chat....guess we stuck here XD. I think my only option is the quick-and-dirty screen-scraping using the Chrome extension. Any idea how I can go about with this? Not a lot of documentation out there...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue has been solved now. I used the Selenium Web Driver, integrated it to VB.NET and then used it to scrape the email. Feel free to comment if you wanna know how I did it. I'm gonna close this question thread now :)